# Grayscale image segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to segment a grayscale picture generated from field measurements, that is why it is not a conventional 3-channel picture.

I have tried this piece of code:

```
import cv2 #this is the openCV library
import numpy as np

# some code to generate img

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img ,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

And it spits out this error:

```
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:719: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::threshold
```

I have no idea on how to solve this since the usage seems to be pretty straight forward, so any idea is welcome.

Comment: How are you creating the image?

Comment: Basically it is a matrix interpolated from sparse values in it. so img is a matrix

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the following assert statement `CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 );` in  `thresh.cpp`, meaning your input image is not of type `CV_8UC1`.

So make sure that your generated input image `img` is in fact `CV_8UC1` (one channel 8-bit image).

Comment: And how do I make the conversion? could it be with img.astype(cv2.CV_8UC1) ??

Comment: It depends on the type of `img`. What is the type of your input image `img`?

Comment: You can use `cv2.convertScaleAbs` for conversion. See the [Documentation.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=convertscale#convertscaleabs) Or you can write your won code for conversion. Make sure you understand what different Mat type are and how they are stored in memory. For example, 8-bit can represent pixel values from 0 to 255, how do you convert say a float value of 1300 to 8-bit value. That requires somehow scaling the float value to fit in 0-255 range.

Answer (score 0):

So indeed the problem is the image type, since it contains double values thay need to be normalized to 0 ~ 255.

in my case 1000 is the maximum value possible

```
img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img / 1000.0 * 255)
```

This worked for me.